# UIView below UINavigation bar on each screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

I want to add `UIView` below `UINavigation` bar on each screen. I don't want to add it on every viewcontroller explicitly. I want to add a view in parent class so that the rest of the views in every viewcontroller starts below the view that I added below `UINavigationBar`. Currently, I have added a view in parent class but it appears over the views in child classes. Any solution?

Comment: why below UINavigationBar? Any specific reason? usually everyone need it over the views...

Comment: @Fahim Basically I want a notification strip there and it has to be the same view in every viewController.

Comment: isn't notification should be above all views?

Comment: do you want to create custom notification like whatsapp when you are on app and any message that show from top one animated view for while

Comment: I would say use [Toast](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/toast) to show notification... Its very easy....

Comment: Can't use Toast. Plus I don't want to show it for a while. I have some adds and promotions stuff that will be shown too.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is i got one very nice helpful github project for show a custom message view under thenavigation bar here is link [TSMessages](https://github.com/KrauseFx/TSMessages)

[image]

Comment: Again the child view is hidden below the parent view. I want the child view to start from a point where parent view ends.

Comment: you need to maitatiomn childe view frame as par you view. and accarind to messge view move up and down

Answer (score 0):

Make your custom UIView in xib and use inheritance concept. Create a BaseViewController and all other view controller should be subclass of your BaseViewController. Load your custom UIView in BaseViewController it will be there all other subclasses

Comment: In that case it appears above the child view controller. Not working

Comment: Can you please put the image of the view controller that your expecting?